# File Not Found Exception while parsing large XML File in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm using SAX (Simple API for XML) to parse an XML document. The document is a huge XML file (dblp.xml - 1.46 GB), i wrote a few lines of parser and tested it on small files and it works.
[image: Here is my projects hierarchy]

Sample.XML and Student.XML are small files having few lines of XML, my parser parses them but when i change the path to dblp.XML it generates the file not found exception (file is still there with other sample files, but its huge in size) 
here is the Exception i get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Workspaces\Java\SaxParser\xml\dblp.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

here is my code:

```
package com.teamincredibles.sax;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class Parser extends DefaultHandler {

  public void getXml() {
    try {
      SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
      final MySet openingTagList = new MySet();
      final MySet closingTagList = new MySet();
      DefaultHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler() {

        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
          System.out.println("Starting Parsing...\n");
        }

        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
          System.out.print("\n\nDone Parsing!");
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
          Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
          if (!openingTagList.contains(qName)) {
            openingTagList.add(qName);
            System.out.print("<" + qName + ">\n");
          }
        }

        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
          /*for(int i=start; i<(start+length);i++){
            System.out.print(ch[i]);
        }*/
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
          if (!closingTagList.contains(qName)) {
            closingTagList.add(qName);
            System.out.print("</" + qName + ">");
          }
        }
      };

      saxParser.parse("xml/dblp.xml", defaultHandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Parser readXml = new Parser();
    readXml.getXml();
  }
}
```

What is the matter i can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your XML file referencing a DTD, in this case "dblp.dtd".

If yes check if its in the location "E:\Workspaces\Java\SaxParser\xml\". If not place it in the location and run your code.

Comment: Thanks it worked but please explain what is this file, i'm a newbie in this field.

Comment: DTD defines the structure of your XML. i.e tags and attributes that can be present e.t.c. Basically, this is a ruleset for your xml that checks if its well formed or not. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition

Comment: Okay thank you so much i got it.
it worked but after that it generated another problem, please answer that too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360962/limit-imposed-by-the-application-while-parsing-xml