# limit imposed by the application while parsing XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm parsing a huge XML file using eclipse juno. It parses few lines of it and then it generates the following exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; The parser has encountered more than "64,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.
```

What should I do now? One of the solution that comes into my mind is to split my XML into multiple small XML files but i can't find any solution to do that too.
You can see my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360901/getting-parent-child-hierarchy-in-sax-xml-parser)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why did you create a new question? You could have just edited the linked one!

Comment: Sorry i thought that might create confusions.

Comment: What JDK are you using. OpenJDK or OracleJDK

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482331/whats-causing-these-parseerror-exceptions-when-reading-off-an-aws-sqs-queue-in

Comment: I'm using Oracle JDK version 1.7

Comment: He is talking about some Storm Workers that's is out of the my understandings.

Comment: @SubhanAhmed You should update your question with new information to make it more complete. Commenting on comments with new information is something you do on a forum, but not on [so] which is a Q&A site. (And when you enhance the post, don't put in **Edit** or **Update**, we can see what changed based on the edit history).

Comment: i'll take care of it sir

Comment: @SubhanAhmed  you should add: some code you tried, and information about size of file, and when it crashes (there seems to be only one line ?)